# What is an alternative to using map function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataset and I need to get a count of reports and I am using map but does not seem to be working.

Sample Data:

```
ID        Manager_ID     Manger_Pos_Num  
101          103              1111
102          103              1111
103          106              2222
104          103              3333 
105          106              2222
106
```

Desired output:

```
 ID     Reports 
 101      0
 102      0
 103      2
 103      1          
 104      0  
 105      0
 106      2
```

I am using

```
counts = df.groupby('Manager_Pos_Num')['ID'].nunique()
df['Reports'] = df['ID'].map(counts).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

When I use this I get all zeros I am not sure why I have checked the counts variable and that works I don't know if its the map function or not any suggestions?

I am using `Manager_Pos_Num` instead of the `ManagerID` for counting because I want to see if that manager has been in another `Manager_Pos_Num`.

Comment: check for matching type of `ID` and `Manager_ID` (int vs. str), if both are string, check for leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: @QuangHoang `ID` is int `Manager_Pos_Num` is  float type

Comment: oh, `Manager_Pos_Num`, but `Manager_Pos_Num` doesn't contain any of `ID`/`Manager_ID`? do you mean `counts=df.groupby('Manger_ID')['Manager_Pos_Num'].nunique()`

Comment: Count has manager position numbers as its keys, but you're tying to use it to map ID numbers. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, so I don't know how to correct this.

Comment: @BenGrossmann What I am trying to do is use the `Manager_Pos_Num` as unique key and use `ID` to check how many IDs report to that position number. and mapping that number to a new column `Reports`

Comment: Ok, so how is the code supposed to "know" which `Manager_Pos_Num` each ID corresponds to?

Comment: Also, notice that it shouldn't be possible to simply set the last column of the dataframe to be your desired result since the desired output has more rows than the original dataframe

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to count the number of unique pairs `(Manager_ID, Manger_Pos_Num)`, so `groupby().size()` and then `merge` instead of `map` because you have duplicates `ID` on the new data (e.g. `103`):

```
df[['ID']].merge(df.groupby(['Manager_ID','Manger_Pos_Num']).size()
                   .reset_index('Manger_Pos_Num', drop='True')
                   .reset_index(name='count'),
                 right_on='Manager_ID', left_on='ID', how='outer'
                ).fillna(0)[['ID','count']]
```

Output:

```
    ID  count
0  101    0.0
1  102    0.0
2  103    2.0
3  103    1.0
4  104    0.0
5  105    0.0
6  106    2.0
```

Comment: When I do this I get a  0.0 for ID and Numbers for count. in those rows

Comment: no, ID actually remains int, but yes, count will be float. It can be casted to int with `df.astype({"count": int})`